# How to make the word in the next line in csv

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like this:

```
['tomorrow', 'space', 'Film']
```

and when I write it to the csv it become:

```
tomorrow,space,Film
```

and my expectation when i write it to csv is like this:

```
tommorrow
space
Film
```

and this is my code

```
with open("Noun.csv", 'wb') as n:
        noun = csv.writer(n)
        noun.writerow(list_noun)
```

How can i fix my code?

Comment: If that's what you want, then don't bother with the `csv` module, just use `n.write('\n'.join(list_noun))` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `csv.writerows`:

```
import csv
s = ['tomorrow', 'space', 'Film']
with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([[i] for i in s])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
list_noun = ['tomorrow', 'space', 'Film']
with open('noun.csv', 'w') as f:
  [csv.writer(f).writerow([word]) for word in list_noun]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `csv` package. Try this:

```
data = ['tomorrow', 'space', 'Film']
with open('_temp.csv', 'w') as handle:
    handle.write("\n".join(data))
```